# Phonegap 2.2 moveTo() fails to exec callback

Tags: cordova

I am using the following code which is called by the navigator.camera.getPicture api:

```
function getImageURI(imageURI) {
    //resolve file system for image to move.
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, gotPicture, function(error) {onfail(error,'Get Target Image');}); 

function gotPicture(targetImg) {    
    //move the image into the post_(n) directory.
    targetImg.moveTo(Globals.POSTDIR_OBJ,Utils.getImageName(), moveSuccess2, function(error){alert('Move Error')} ); 

        function moveSuccess2(){
            alert('addPicture moveSuccess');

            //update the picture counts in the client and DB.
            Globals.pictCount++;
            updateFilesById();
            setTimeout("Gallery.show()",500);  
        };
    }; //gotPicture 



}; //getImageURI
```

The problem is about 30% of the time neither the success or the fail callback functions are called.

The move is actually successful every time, but the success function fails to execute about 1/3 the time.

Answer (score 0):

Just gonna try a wild guess on this one. My guess is that because of the asynchronous nature of the success callback that occasionally the success function hasn't been defined yet due to the unpredictability of threading. Try moving the declaration of the moveSuccess2 function to somewhere its declaration will always be finished before calling the the moveTo function. That could mean declaring as a function outside of the gotPicture function, or declaring as an anonymous function like your error handler, or declaring it just before you make the call to moveTo.